# Limit number of columns in masonry isFitWidth centered layout

Tags: javascript, css, masonry

I am struggling on this problem for some time now;
I am creating this layout:

http://www.nomdeplume.it/layout_new/

and my problem is that I can't set a maximum number of elements per rows;
I mean columns number adapt when browser resize, but I want it to be 4 at maximum.

It seems a banal problem, 
why there is not an option to do that?
Another way would be to set a margin or something, but isFitWidth doesn't work with a specific width or margin.

here is the code

```
   $('#container').imagesLoaded( function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.item',
   isAnimated: true,
   columWidth: 270,
   gutter: 18,
   transitionDuration: 0,
   isFitWidth: true
  });
});
```

the css is simple, like for isFitWidth option

```
#container{ margin: 100px auto; }
```

Comment: sorry i edited my answer with it

Answer (score 4):

If you want a max column number of 4 columns then wrap the masonry container in another dev and give that div a max-width of 4*column width.

like this:

```
<div class="masonry_container">
 <div id="container">
 masonry stuff here
 </div>
</div>
```

then give the container a max-width like this:

```
.masonry_container {
max-width: 1080px; /* 4* masonry column width  */
}
```